# How can I output a nice neat column?

Tags: c++, output

I want the output format to align-right. My code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Planet
{
    string name;
    double volume;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Planet planets[3]={{"太阳",22.1e20},{"地球",4.2e7},{"海王星",5.3e10}};
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<right<<"\t"<<planets[i].name<<setw(12)<<planets[i].volume<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code. The output is llike in the picture below, but it's not what I want. Because the output columns cannot align-right.

[image]

Comment: Try this `cout<<right<<" 太阳系"<<"\t"<<12.33322023<<endl<<" 星系"<<"\t"<<32.2323324402<<endl;`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Question has been updated.

As per documentation, [std::right](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) is filling stream from right side and [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) is for setting width parameter of the stream. In your case, `std::right << std::setw(12)` must fall just before the thing you want to format(particularly in MacOS X). Thus solution is:

```
Planet planets[3] = { {"AB",22.1e20},{"AB",4.2e7},{"ABC",5.3e10} };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << right << setw(12) << planets[i].name << right << setw(12) << planets[i].volume << endl;
}
return 0;
```

This gives Output like this:

[image]

My console doesn't support printing of multi-byte characters. That's why i replaced them with characters of same length. If I use them, I get following output but formatting is correct:

[image]

Thanks to @Ted ,godbolt has helped me come-up with as generic solution as possible. There seems to be some issue in printing multi-byte characters with `std::setw`.

```
Planet planets[5]={{u8"太阳",22.1e20},{u8"地球球",4.2e7},{u8"海王星",5.3e10} , {u8"海王星星",5.3e10} , {u8"海王星星星",5.3e10} };
size_t min_size = 0;
size_t max_size = 0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    max_size = max(max_size , planets[i].name.size());  
    min_size = min(min_size , planets[i].name.size());
}

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  cout << right << setw(max_size + (planets[i].name.size() - min_size)/2 )<< planets[i].name << right << setw( max_size ) << planets[i].volume << endl;
}
```

This is how it prints:

[image]

You could revert printing order of your struct's members and get a better output.

[image]

Comment: std::w -> std::setw

Comment: @E.N.D  Sir, I just tried your code, but the output is not what I want. I want each column to align-right.

Comment: @TeixTang First off, There's no need for honorafics like Sir. Secondly,  I have added image in answer. Please check.

Comment: @E.N.D You can use [godbolt](http://godbolt.org/) to test how your solution works with the UTF-8 characters OP uses. In its current state, your solution does not work. The length of `太阳系` is 9 `char`s and `星系` is 6 `char`s.

Comment: You use `min_size` and `max_size` uninitialized so you have undefined behaviour. Also, using `size()` calculations to try to figure out how wide multibyte character strings will be when displayed is likely to go horribly wrong I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: I have initialized both of them but I am not so sure about your second argument. Since, std::setw is not able to set correct width and there's no alternative in standard library, I am afraid i'm left with no choice but to compute width on my own.